# Error "Unable to find modules for some sources..." in Dart

Tags: angular, dart, routes

I'm learning dart and trying to make a simple webapp, which should make it possible to create an user.

But when I'm trying to run it, the following message appears:

> [SEVERE] build_web_compilers|entrypoint on web/main.dart (cached):
> Unable to find modules for some sources, this is usually the result of either a
> bad import, a missing dependency in a package (or possibly a dev_dependency
> needs to move to a real dependency), or a build failure (if importing a
> generated file).
>
> Please check the following imports:
>
> `import 'package:Muellbot/app_component.template.dart' as ng;`
> from Muellbot|web/main.template.dart at 9:1
> `import 'package:Muellbot/app_component.template.dart' as ng;`
> from Muellbot|web/main.dart at 2:1
>
> [SEVERE] Failed after 2.2s

Here are my files:

main.dart

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:Muellbot/app_component.template.dart' as ng;
import 'package:angular_router/angular_router.dart';

import 'main.template.dart' as self;

@GenerateInjector(
  routerProvidersHash,
)
final InjectorFactory injector = self.injector;

void main() {
  runApp(ng.AppComponentNgFactory, createInjector: injector);
}
```

appComponent.dart

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_router/angular_router.dart';

import 'src/routes.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: ['app_component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
  directives: [routerDirectives],
  exports: [RoutePaths, Routes],

)
class AppComponent {

}
```

appComponent.html

```
<h1>Müllbot</h1>
<nav>
    <a [routerLink]="RoutePaths.home.toUrl()"
   [    routerLinkActive]="'active'">Home</a>
    <a [routerLink]="RoutePaths.newUser.toUrl()"
       [routerLinkActive]="'active'">Neuen Benutzer anlegen</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet [routes]="Routes.all"></router-outlet>
<img src="logo.png" width="50%">
```

routes.dart

```
import 'package:angular_router/angular_router.dart';

import 'route_paths.dart';
import 'home_component.template.dart' as home_template;
import 'create_new_user_component.template.dart' as new_user_template;

export 'route_paths.dart';

class Routes {
  static final home = RouteDefinition(
    routePath: RoutePaths.home,
    component: home_template.HomeComponentNgFactory,
  );
  static final newUser = RouteDefinition(
    routePath: RoutePaths.newUser,
    component: new_user_template.NewUserComponentNgFactory,
  );

  static final all = <RouteDefinition>[
    home,
    newUser,
  ];
}
```

routhe_paths.dart

```
import 'package:angular_router/angular_router.dart';

class RoutePaths {
  static final home = RoutePath(path: 'home');
  static final newUser = RoutePath(path: 'newUser');

}
```

home_component.html

```
    <h4>Hallo {{user.firstName}}</h4>
```

home_component.dart

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

import 'user.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: 'home_component.html'
)

class HomeComponent {

  User user = new User('Axel', 'Foley', 'axel@sfoley.de');

}
```

create_new_user_component.html

```
<h3>Neuen Benutzer anlegen</h3>
<div>
    <span *ngIf="!create" id="error">Fehler</span>
    <span *ngIf="create" id="success">Benutzer angelegt</span>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Vorname:</label></td><td><input #firstName/></td>
            <td><label>Nachname:</label></td><td><input #lastName/></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><label>Email:</label></td><td><input #email/></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><label>Passwort:</label></td><td><input #password/></td>
            <td><label>Passwort wiederholen:</label></td><td><input #passwordRe/></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><button (click)="add(firstName.value, lastName.value, email.value, password.value)">Hinzufügen</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

create_new_user_component.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';


@Component(
  selector: 'new-user',
  templateUrl: 'create_new_user_component.html'
)

class NewUserComponent {
  bool create = false;
  final Client _http;
  static final _headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
  final url = "http://localhost:4040/user/new";

  Future<void> add(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password) async {
    try {
      final response = await _http.post(url, headers: _headers, body: json.encode({'firstName': firstName, 'lastName': lastName, 'email': email, 'password': password}));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        create = true;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Exception(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: At least from your example above, you wrote `templateUrl: 'app_component.html'`, but named your HTML file `appComponent.html`. That might be the source of your issue?

Comment: Thank, but it's a mistake, the files are named "app_component.*"

Comment: If you look in your `.dart_tool/build/generated/Muellbot/lib/` directory, do you see the `app_component.template.dart` file?

Comment: No, there is no such a file.

Comment: Ok - so for some reason then it is not being generated. Do you have any other errors in your build?

You could also navigate to /$graph (in serve mode), and in the search box type in "lib/app_component.template.dart" and click search. Does it find a node? If so can you copy/past the information for it in the top right corner?

Comment: This is the output: Error requesting query "ib/app_component.template.dart".
404 Not Found
Could not find asset for path "ib/app_component.template.dart". Tried:
- Muellbot|ib/app_component.template.dart
- Muellbot|web/ib/app_component.template.dart

Comment: It looks like you missed the leading `l`, should be `lib/app_component.template.dart`

Comment: Oh, you are right, I'm sorry. So here is the right output: 
    ID: Muellbot|lib/app_component.template.dart
    Generated: true
    Hidden: true
    State: NodeState.mayNeedUpdate
    Was Output: false
    Failed: true
    Phase: 907
    Globs: null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179932/discussion-between-jake-macdonald-and-jupper).

Answer (score 0):

Ok removing

```
<span *ngIf="!create" id="error">Fehler</span>
<span *ngIf="create" id="success">Benutzer angelegt</span>
```

helped.

But now I got another error. The server loads and when I visit the page, it just says

```
Loading...
```

In the console I get the message

```
TypeError: e.message is undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by importing the packages in full which includes your Project `dir path` in your `routes.dart`
make sure imports look like this

```
import 'package:Muellbot/home_component.template.dart' as home_template;
import 'package:Muellbot/create_new_user_component.template.dart' as new_user_template;
```

and not this

```
import 'home_component.template.dart' as home_template;
import 'create_new_user_component.template.dart' as new_user_template;
```